# Make two flex items each 50% height of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using css flex layout to build a dashboard and would like to put two widgets (one on top of the other) inside of a flex item and make them 50% height of their parent at all times (regardless of content). So if my html is:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="widget" id="w1">
      widget 1 content
    </div>
    <div class="widget" id="w2">
      widget 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css looks like:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

How can I get the two `.widget`s to always occupy 50% height of `.flex-item`?

I've tried:

```
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.widget {
  flex: 1;
}
```

But this only works when the content in both widgets are the same.

I've worked up a more [elaborate jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89y4roz7/1/) to better illustrate my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm...normally I would say `flex:0 0 50%` in a columns layout would be enough but it's the overflow that's the issue I think or the lack of a defined height. Probably the latter...certainly in Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say that `flex: 1` *only works when the content in both widgets are the same*, that is not correct. That would defeat the purpose of `flex: 1`.

`flex: 1` tells flex items to distribute container space evenly among themselves. If there are four flex items with `flex: 1`, each will take 25%. Three would take 33.33%. And two flex items will take 50%. This is *regardless of content quantity*.

See this illustration: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/m6njy4t9/1/)

---

The problem you're having is not clear in the code you posted in the question. However, it's apparent in your fiddle demo.

You have a main container with a `height: 400px`. You also have a rule adding 10px padding all-around to your divs. This adds 20px height to each div. You also have a header with `height: 2em`.

When you account for the extra heights the layout works.

Try these adjustments:

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
div {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(30, 100, 200, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;                    /* sneaky villain */
    font-family: arial;
}

h1, p { margin: 0; }

#main-wrapper {
    height: 400px;                    /* primary height */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 2em;                      /* header height */
}

#main-column-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: calc(100% - 2em - 20px);  /* primary height - header height - padding */
}

#side-column {
    width: 20%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#main-column {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);      /* main-column-wrapper height - padding (2 divs) */
}

#widget1,
#widget2 {
    flex: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/89y4roz7/3/)

Another option would be to use `box-sizing: border-box` to adjust for the padding. Learn more here: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: I had learned of calc() a while back but didn't know what use cases it could be for. Thanks so much for the help!